# SQL Column that ensure consecutivity of the values of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to have a column that always ensure the connectivity of it's value.

Example

Having a table orders.

| id | ord |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 6 |
| 7 | 7 |

In this table if I want to update the last line (7) to have the ord 3 then the table should look like this

| id | ord |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 7 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 6 |
| 6 | 7 |

All the rows beneath the updated value increased their order

In the same way, if I want to remove a line 7 from this updated table, then I want to have

| id | ord |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 6 |

Is this possible in sql?

I tried implementing a trigger for this but I failed

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: why not create a view where this column could be just a simple row_number over something or other

Comment: I agree with @siggemannen a column as ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ORD) as [ORDER] in a view should suffice, then you order by it, if not a view, then the whole thing as subquery then you order by [ORDER] column.

Comment: Do you actually need to guarantee the `ord` column is sequential, using a constraint?